# How to expose 'require' to the browser when using browserify from within gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify

When I have a file x.js that looks like this:

x.js

```
module.exports = function (n) { return n * 111 }
```

and I run browserify from the command line like so:

```
browserify -r ./x.js > bundle.js
```

I get an output file that looks like this (roughly):

```
require=(function e(t,n,r){function ......
./App.jsx":[function(require,module,exports){
module.exports=require('0+DPR/');
},{}]},{},[])
```

Then in my browser code I can do this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>React server rendering example</title>
    <script src="static/bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Welcome to the React server rendering example. Here is a server-rendered React component:
    <div id="53a442ff8b39d"></div><script>
    var x = require('./x.js');
    console.log(x(3))
</script>  </body>
</html>
```

I actually have two questions:

1) This doesn't quite work in the browser I get the error: "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './x.js'". Why is that happening?

2) I actually want to run this in gulp using vinyl-source-stream. I've tried doing something like this in my gulpfile but it doesn't work. Any ideas? I get the error 'require is not defined'

```
var   gulp = require('gulp'),
  browserify = require('browserify'),
  source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

var b = browserify({
    entries: ['./x.js'],
  });
   b.bundle({debug: false})
   .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
```

Comment: In your command-line example you are writing `bundle.js` into the same folder as `x.js`, but your HTML is reading it from `static/bundle.js`, and in your `gulp` example you are writing it to `build/bundle.js`. Which one is actually the one you want?

Comment: Let's just assume I do the appropriate mv bundle.js command to put it in the right place for the webserver to access. That's not the crux of the problem here.

Comment: Hopefully this [github project](https://github.com/erichosick/nodeboxrequire) will help. It shows how to require and export libraries, the html, the gulp file, etc.

Answer (score 7):

**Update:** You can reference an alias in your -r switch

Try:  `browserify -r ./x.js:my-module > bundle.js`

And in your page:  `var x = require('my-module');`

NOTE:  if you used an -r switch on a node module like **fs** or **through**, you don't need an alias for these because they usually have a name in their package.json file.

See **[node-browserify -- external requires](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#external-requires)** for more info.

---

If you are going to bundle your x.js like that (with -r switch) there are a couple of options

1) Take the script in your html page and bundle it separately.

Create a **main.js** file and put your JS in it.

Use `browserify -x ./x.js > main.js`

By using the -x switch, Browserify will link your **bundle.js** in as a dependancy.

Then reference both JS files in your page.

2) Use name generated by Browserify.

`var x = require('0+DPR/');`

See **Update** above to create an alias.

Good resource below since you are looking to go further with Gulp

- **[Browserify - Bring Nodejs modules to browsers](http://truongtx.me/2014/03/20/browserify-bring-nodejs-modules-to-browser/)**

For more Gulp + Browserify (uses Watchify as well for livereload) Check out blog post on Viget

- **[Gulp + Browserify: The Everything Post](http://viget.com/extend/gulp-browserify-starter-faq)**

Answer (score 4):

Actually you got pretty close, except for two things:

1. you need to expose your `'x.js'` with an exposed name that you can use to require() later, for e.g.: `'x'` is a good choice in your case
2. instead of `require('./x.js');`  you should do `require('x');`

So to give you the full answer:

in `lib/x.js`

```
module.exports = function (n) { return n * 111 }
```

in `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var transform = require('vinyl-transform');

gulp.task('build-lib', function () {

  var browserified = transform(function(filename) {
    return browserify(filename)
      .require(filename, { expose: 'x'})
      .bundle();
  });
  return gulp.src('./lib/x.js')
    .pipe(browserified)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist')); // currently this recipe will output to ./dist/x.js. you may use a rename plugin to output it with a different filename for eg. bundle.js
});

gulp.task('default', ['build-lib']);
```

in an HTML doc (`index.html`)

```
<html>
...
<script src='dist/x.js'></script>
<script>
   var x = require('x');
   console.log(x(3));
</script>
```

**A little bit details about the gulp recipe:**

I used `vinyl-transform` instead `vinyl-source-stream`.

You can choose to use `vinyl-source-stream` but you have to remember to pipe in `vinyl-buffer` right after that if you have more transformations using plugins that works on buffered vinyl file objects (instead of streaming vinyl file object that `vinyl-source-stream` gives out)

What `vinyl-transform` does is that it takes care of both buffered and streaming vinyl file objects for you.