# How do I export my browserified modules for requiring in the browser?

Tags: javascript, browserify, commonjs

I have several js modules that I bundle with browserify in gulp:

```
gulp.task('build:js', ['clean:js'], function () {
  browserify({
    debug: true,
    entries: paths.js.src
  })
    .transform('babelify', { presets: ['es2015'] })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.js.dist));
});
```

It outputs a single `bundle.js`. However, when bundled like this I can't `require` individual modules in the browser. Which I'd like to do, because I don't want to always initiate every module (some are page specific). Instead of that I'd like to be able to use `var someModule = require('some-module');` on a page alongside the bundle.

Now I couldn't really find anything about this in the documentation, since it only documents the commandline options (and not the js api). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25289899/4210742) shows that a module can be required and exposed from gulp, but that would expose my entire bundle, and not the modules of which it is composed.

A solution would be to bundle all my modules separately, exclude dependencies (so they won't be duplicated across bundles) and then concatenate that. But that doesn't really seem like a viable solution because:

1. The modules might have trouble resolving dependencies since everything is bundled separately, and thus dependencies would have to be resolved in-browser. Not ideal and prone to breakage I think.
2. It is very labour intensive since I use a lot of modules, and each will have to be exported manually in gulp, dependencies excluded and referenced in my templates. [There are ways to automate it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26917966/4210742), but this doesn't exclude shared dependencies.

So how do I solve this? How can I require the bundles of which my js is composed separately in the browser, for client side use?

Comment: You'll want to look into code chunking. It's a lot easier in Webpack, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing is something else. What I was asking kind of went against the way that browserify works, even though it's possible. Maybe eventually when HTTP2 imports and [js modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) can be used in all major browsers this'll be easier.

For now, I just have a `global` bundle for the scripts that run on every page, including all my third party libraries. And then for each page I have an separate entry point with the local modules that it needs. This is so far the most maintainable solution.